# Horizontal recyclerview with NestedScrollView load gif with glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide, android-nestedscrollview

I am using Horizontal recyclerview  inside NestedScrollView. when i want to scroll faster inside horizontal scroll view it fling go to above of the view. and recyclerview not much smooth.

- Note: when I load gif image then it happen but when jpg image load
  never go to above of the view. but not smooth any time as expected.

All recyclerview data bind

```
    RecyclerViewDataAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewDataAdapter(getActivity(), allSampleData);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Section data initialize

```
    SectionListDataAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new SectionListDataAdapter(mContext, singleSectionItems, sectionName,itemRowHolder.previewImage);
    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(itemListDataAdapter));
    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="0dp" />
```

Image load

```
Glide.with(MyApplication.applicationContext) // replace with 'this' if it's in activity
                .load(previewUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20"))
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }


                })

                .into(holder.itemImage);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recyclerview inside Nested Scrollview scroll but does not fast scroll like normal Recyclerview or Nested Scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301724/recyclerview-inside-nested-scrollview-scroll-but-does-not-fast-scroll-like-norma)

Comment: Please read my question fast. and all solution i already try but nothing halp me

Answer (score 0):

I found solution my self , This happen with glide library. you can use Facebook fresco library for gif load.