# Use two RecyclerView with different adapter inside NestedScrollView load very slowly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I need to use two RecyclerView with different Adapter in the same view.

My First RecyclerView will load just once in onCreate.

My Second RecyclerView will load more and more data when user scroll to bottom and call the api to get new data.

When I let my Second RecyclerView call the api to load more and more data, it will load very slowly and scroll heavy.

How can I fix that, thank you!

Here is my fragment:

```
public class NewFragment extends Fragment {

    private void setRecyclerAndAdapter(){
        if(swipeRefreshLayout != null && postRecycler != null){

            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context); 
            postRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

            LayoutAnimationController animationController = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_animation_up_to_down);
            postRecycler.setLayoutAnimation(animationController);

            if(postAdAdapter == null){
                postAdAdapter = new PostCardAdapter(context, postDataList);
                postRecycler.setAdapter(postAdAdapter);

                setListener();
            }else{
                postAdAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }else
            return;
    }
.
    private void setListener(){
        if(swipeRefreshLayout != null && postRecycler != null){

            ......

            nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                    if(v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1) != null) {
                        if ((scrollY >= (v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight())) &&
                                scrollY > oldScrollY) {

                            visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                            totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                            pastVisiblesItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                            if(controlCanGetMorePostData == true){
                                controlCanGetMorePostData = false;

                                if(postAdAdapter != null){
                                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                                        postAdAdapter.setLoadState(postAdAdapter.LOADING);
                                        callApiManagerGetMoreData();
                                    }
                                }else
                                    return;
                            }
                            else{
                                hasMorePostData = false;
                                setMoreDataState();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }else
            return;
    }

}
```

Here is my Layout:

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_new_swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_new_nestedScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">

                <GridLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:columnCount="1"
                    android:rowCount="2">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/fragment_new_banner_content"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_row="0">

                                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                                    android:id="@+id/fragment_new_first_recycler"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

                                <com.gmpsykr.each.Game.BannerIndicator
                                    android:id="@+id/fragment_new_banner_indicator"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fragment_new_banner_recycler"
                                    app:selectColor="@color/colorAccent"
                                    app:unselectedColor="#ffffff"
                                    app:radius="3dp"
                                    app:space="10dp" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/fragment_new_second_recycler"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_up_to_down"
                            android:layout_row="1" />

                </GridLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37337641/9248098

Comment: @GowthamKK I tried, it has same problem.

Comment: @GowthamKK if you disabled `nestedScrolling` then `RecyclerView` will stop scrolling the view, that actually defeat the purpose of having it

Comment: @AshwiniViolet Ok Thanks for letting me know. I haven't worked on nestedScrolling

Comment: Remove internal RelativeLayout. Just keep RecyclerView in LinearLayout

Comment: @VVB This RelativeLayout which will contain my another RecyclerView, because I want to use two RecyclerView in the same view, so I can't remove it.

Comment: Please see [https://stackoverflow.com/a/37337641/11560055](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37337641/11560055) I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_new_swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                                <RelativeLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                    android:background="@color/colorAppPrimaryRed" />

                                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                                    android:id="@+id/fragment_new_recycler"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                                    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_up_to_down" />

                        </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: I want when I scroll recyclerview, the item above recyclerview will scroll together. I tried your method, the item will always in the top.

Answer (score 0):

I want you to read this [article](https://android.jlelse.eu/recyclerview-within-nestedscrollview-scrolling-issue-3180b5ad2542) and the same problem at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37337641/11560055.

I think this will be an answer for your problem.

Comment: I add recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false), but not work.