# nested scroll view(scrolling) is lagging when loading image URLs using Glide

Tags: java, android, android-studio, scroll

When I remove glide from the code, then it is scrolling perfectly.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288436/recyclerview-laggy-scrolling) and [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1088) but i am unable to resolve the issue.

this is my main_activity code

```
                           if(finalI == size-1) {
                               Collections.reverse(posts_list);
                               ImageListAdapter adapter = new ImageListAdapter(posts_list);

                               LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                               linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);


                               recyclerView_in_profile.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                               recyclerView_in_profile.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                               recyclerView_in_profile.setAdapter(adapter);


                           }
```

this is my adapter code for loading images into each item of recycler view.

```
  public class ImageListAdapter_forAdd extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Activity context;
private int resource;
private List<String> listImage;

ImageListAdapter_forAdd(@NonNull Activity context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    listImage = objects;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder") View v = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
    //  TextView tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(tvImageName);


    v.layout(0,0,0,0);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgView);

    // tvName.setText(listImage.get(position).getName());5555


    Glide.with(context).load(listImage.get(position)).into(img);


    return v;

}
}
```

in another fragment I just used the same code for recycler view , its working fine , but here in nested scrolling it seems there might be some issue with glide.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Rahul, ever figured that one out?